# Is there a way to connect SQL Server local database to Google Sheet?

Tags: sql-server

What I've tried:

1. Using third party app (SeekWell), it is not compatible with old version of windows
2. Using Google App Script, unfortunately it is not working with local database
3. Using another third party app, but all of them not working with local database

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Which direction are you trying to go - please explain more about what you are trying to do other than just "connect".

Comment: At least it can run stored procedure from SQL server, input the stored procedure parameter, and show the result on Google Sheet. Only showing data based on query inputed is okay.

Comment: So you are trying to get a cloud based app to access your local sql environment? That would involve exposing your local server to the internet. You should be looking at a cloud database as well - if its sql server then an azure sql instance is probably your best bet.